# Couchbase server not starting

Tags: centos, couchbase

I have installed `couchbase-server-enterprise-4.5.0-DP1-centos6.x86_64.rpm` for centOS. The installation was successful.

```
rpm --install couchbase-server-enterprise-4.5.0-DP1-centos7.x86_64.rpm
```

gives me

```
package couchbase-server-4.5.0-1308.x86_64 is already installed
```

but I am not able to start it by giving the `sudo /etc/init.d/couchbase-server start` command. I am getting the following error.

```
Starting couchbase-server
/opt/couchbase/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.4.0.0.1/bin/erlexec: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/couchbase/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.4.0.0.1/bin/erlexec)
                                                       [FAILED]
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Why would you not be using systemctl? That is how you need to be doing it for centos 7.

Comment: ok, in relooking at this. You give two different RPMs. One for centOS 6 and one for CentOS 7. What version of CentOS are you actually running and does it match to the Couchbase RPM to OS version?